# Values within primary key occasionally changes over time

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

I got some data defined in a table in a MySQL database like this

```
CREATE TABLE `T_dev` (
    id          VARCHAR(20)         NOT NULL,
    date        DATETIME            NOT NULL,
    amount      VARCHAR(9)      DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id,date)
);
```

I then insert a record, for example

```
INSERT INTO T_dev VALUES 
('10000','2009-08-05 23:00:00','35')
```

However, one month later I get a report that tells me that this exact record should have amount equal to 30, thus

```
INSERT INTO T_dev VALUES 
('10000','2009-08-05 23:00:00','30')
```

However, that can´t be done because of the primary key I´ve defined. I would like to overwrite the old record with the new one, but not really change my primary key. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Alexander

Comment: you can use "on duplicate key update"

Comment: Did you really choose the correct PK? Can your system live with the wrong PK? What about related rows?

Comment: Yes. I did INSERT INTO T_dev VALUES 
('10000','2009-08-05 23:00:00','30')
ON duplicate key update kwh_t=values(kwh_t); This is my first post, what do I do to vote on answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the record already exists, you don't use the INSERT statement.  Instead use an UPDATE statement to change the value to 30 for that specific id and date combination:

```
UPDATE T_dev SET amount = '30' 
WHERE id = '10000' AND date = '2009-08-05 23:00:00'
```

Just an observation, your table is a little out of the norm.  Typically primary keys are of type `INT` and your `amount` would probably be better off as a `DECIMAL`.

Comment: You are missing the where clause for date, as it is a part of the primary key also

Comment: Thank you. However, typically I would load data from a text-file that I get, like LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Y:text.csv' INTO TABLE T_dev. In advance I do not know whether the id='10000" AND date = '2009-08-05 23:00:00' changed into amount = '30'. Any way I can get that load data statement to update those records in the same fashion you suggests?

Comment: This solved it
ON duplicate key update amount=values(amount);

Answer (score 3):

use an update statement

```
UPDATE T_dev
SET amount = 30
WHERE id=10000 AND date = '2009-08-05 23:00:00'
```